# servlet load exception

Tags: java, servlets

When i try and run at server i am getting the following severe error:

I have the latest Spring-servlet and spring-ws jars included in my path.
I do not want to overburden with adding code you wont need so any sections you think i should include let me know.
Im sure it is just something small i have forgotten or missplaced.

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
02/07/2012 1:56:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet weather as unavailable
02/07/2012 1:56:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup    

SEVERE: Servlet /weatherWS threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
29/06/2012 3:29:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
29/06/2012 3:29:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
29/06/2012 3:29:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 232 ms
```

I have double checked and i do have org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet included under my spring-ws jar. This folder is included under libraries build path still hitting the same problem.

Comment: Can you please check once again if jar file containing "org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet" class is present in build path?

Comment: On further checking i do have spring ws 2.0.2 with org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet in the project and it is on the buildpath. now i am just confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old link, but it should point you in the right direction:

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/443071/Spring/spring-MessageDispatcherServlet-class-not-found

Here are results from jarfinder.com:

- http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet

Bottom line: make sure you've got the right spring-ws-core-xxx.jar

Comment: ill have a look and get back to you

Comment: org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet is in the project under spring_ws_2.0.2 and in the buildpath.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure have one of the `spring-ws-*.jar` in your `classpath`, Log itself says it can not find class.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
```

jars containing this class can be find [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet).

Answer (score 1):

make sure you copy the relevant jar containing org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
 in your WEB-INF/lib directory

Jars conatining this class are found here http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet